# JSoup - select more than one item

Tags: java, web, web-scraping, jsoup

i am experimenting in extracting information from this file:

```
<tr id="ctl00_Body_mc_cErgebnisListe1_ctl02_InseratInfoTR" class="topangebot"> 
 <td class="BildTD" rowspan="2"> <a href="/anzeiger/immoweb/Detail.aspx?InseratID=6629161&amp;FromTopAngebot=true"><img border="0" src="http://images.derstandard.at/t/22/upload/imagesanzeiger/immoupload/2012/05/73/733de246-b4eb-425a-8705-2e8b50baff12.jpg" alt="" /></a> </td> 
 <td class="TitleTD" rowspan="2"> <span class="neu">TOP!</span> <strong><a href="/anzeiger/immoweb/Detail.aspx?InseratID=6629161&amp;FromTopAngebot=true">Ihr Geld als sichere Anlage - Eigentum vom Feinsten - Jacquingasse 29</a></strong><br /><a href="/anzeiger/immoweb/Detail.aspx?InseratID=6629161&amp;FromTopAngebot=true">Wien 3.,Landstra&szlig;e, Wohnung</a><br /><span style="color: gray">Erstbezug, Parkettboden, Lift, Provisionsfrei, Kabel/Sat-TV</span> </td> 
 <td class="GroessenTD" rowspan="2"> </td> 
 <td class="PreisTD" style="border:none;"> </td> 
</tr>
<tr id="ctl00_Body_mc_cErgebnisListe1_ctl02_InseratInfoTR" class="topangebot"> 
 <td class="BildTD" rowspan="2"> <a href="/anzeiger/immoweb/Detail.aspx?InseratID=6629161&amp;FromTopAngebot=true"><img border="0" src="http://images.derstandard.at/t/22/upload/imagesanzeiger/immoupload/2012/05/73/733de246-b4eb-425a-8705-2e8b50baff12.jpg" alt="" /></a> </td> 
 <td class="TitleTD" rowspan="2"> <span class="neu">TOP!</span> <strong><a href="/anzeiger/immoweb/Detail.aspx?InseratID=6629161&amp;FromTopAngebot=true">Ihr Geld als sichere Anlage - Eigentum vom Feinsten - Jacquingasse 29</a></strong><br /><a href="/anzeiger/immoweb/Detail.aspx?InseratID=6629161&amp;FromTopAngebot=true">Wien 3.,Landstra&szlig;e, Wohnung</a><br /><span style="color: gray">Erstbezug, Parkettboden, Lift, Provisionsfrei, Kabel/Sat-TV</span> </td> 
 <td class="GroessenTD" rowspan="2">12312 </td> 
 <td class="PreisTD" style="border:none;">3123 </td> 
</tr>
```

I want to select with my css query the title and the price from the same tr.topangebot at the same time. I tried this query:

```
Elements topangebotPars = doc.select("tr.topangebot > (td.TitleTD && td.GroesseTD)");
```

I got:

> Could not parse query

How to select more than one element at the same time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember that the selectors used with [`select`](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html#select%28java.lang.String%29) are CSS selectors. So just like you'd write a [comma-separated list of selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#grouping) in a CSS file, for instance:

```
tr.topangebot > td.TitleTD, tr.topangebot > td.GroesseTD {
    color: blue:
}
```

...you do the same thing with `select`:

```
Elements topangebotPars = doc.select("tr.topangebot > td.TitleTD, tr.topangebot > td.GroesseTD");
```

The JSoup documentation has a [quick reference](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Selector.html) for selectors. They list this under "combinators" (although the CSS spec itself doesn't consider them "combinators," just a group).

Comment: Thx for your answer!!! At the moment I get also the html attributes back. Do you have a good idea how to get rid of them? And how to insert delimiter to cut the strings much more easily?

Comment: @maximus: I don't know JSoup well enough to know about the attributes aspect. As for the other, you could write them on separate lines using string concatenation.